# RxJava doesn't work in Scheduler.io() thread

Tags: java, rx-java

The problem in that: I have `Observable` and `Subscriber`. I try to launch `Observable` in `.io()` thread, because it works with files and zip archivers (I won't show the code - is too large), but `Observable` do nothing!:

```
Observable<Double> creatingObservable = getCreatingObservable(image);
Subscriber<Double> creatingSubscriber = getCreatingSubscriber();

creatingObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(creatingSubscriber);
```

If I launch code without the `subscribeOn()` - all work. What is the problem and how to solve it

P.S. System.out.println() doesn't work too. Problem have all Scheduler's threads.

Comment: the problems description sounds like your main thread terminates before creatingObservable can emit. so just to be sure: if you put a Thread.sleep(5000) at the end, does it still not work?

Comment: @SimonZ., точно! :о

Comment: @SimonZ., that is, it is! How could I have thought of! Please, add this to answer.

Comment: done, added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the main thread terminated before `creatingObservable` could emit any values.

The simple solution: make the main thread wait long enough to enable `creatingObservable` to emit/complete.

```
Observable<Double> creatingObservable = getCreatingObservable(image);
Subscriber<Double> creatingSubscriber = getCreatingSubscriber();

creatingObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(creatingSubscriber);

Thread.sleep(5000); //to wait 5 seconds while creatingObservable is running on IO thread
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
Subscriber<Double> creatingSubscriber = getCreatingSubscriber();
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Double>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Double> call() {
        return getCreatingObservable(image);
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(creatingSubscriber);
```

Don't forget to add:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
```

From here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

## Explanation

`getCreatingObservable(image);` - most probably you use some operators which do 'hard' work in moment of call.

## For example:

```
Observable.just(doSomeStuff())
    .subscribeOn(...)
    .observeOn(...)
```

So, the execution process will be:

1). Calculate `doSomeStuff()`

2). Pass result to `Observable.just()`

3). And only passing you are applying schedulers

In other words, you are doing 'hard' work firstly, and then applying schedulers.

That's why you need to use `Observable.defer()`

For more explanation, please read this article of Dan Lew:
http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/

Section **Old, Slow Code**

Comment: Thatnks, Your suggestion very useful. But my problem was in other - main tread closed, when `Observable` try to start. And why main thread doesn't wait, when `RxJava-thread` closed...

Comment: 1). What does "main tread closed" mean? Actually, I absolutelly don't understand it.... Can you clarify it for me please?  2). What is "RxJava-thread"?  3). When RxJava-thread is closed? If you want, we may discuss in the chat to figure out with your problem

Comment: sorry, I very badly speak english. I try to told, that "main thread closed" - it's mean that main thread of my program finished executed, before thread, which created RxJava. RxJava-thread - it's thread, which RxJava created (maybe in english forbidden create such words.. :)). In answer, that I accept, there is a solution to my problem (temperaly, of course. I created GUI and my problem will disappear)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you app create observable just once. You may try to either use
`Observable.defer(()-> creatingObservable)` so `.defer` operator will force observable creation every time.

```
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Double>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Double> call() {
                return getCreatingObservable();
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(getCreatingSubscriber);
```